# failed to load bundle localhost 8081 index.bundle platform=ios cannot find entry file index.js in any of the roots

Tags: react-native

For about the last 24 hours I decided to take my react native project off expo. So I ejected it and started to doing the proper troubleshooting to run my app using react-native run-ios. I have managed to make my application's build succeed via Xcode however when the application runs I constantly get an [ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ViJ8v.png). I noticed within my react native file I don't have an index.js. Not really sure why not and how to make one. I did try running `react-native init`, however, that just made my build fail and I had to go through a whole process to make it work again. Any help would be very much appreciated.

NOTE: I am not able to embed images at my level. So, I do apologize for the link

[package.json + look at my files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UqLyL.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an `index.js` in your root with the following:

```
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import App from './App';

AppRegistry.registerComponent('YourAppName', () => App);
```